# javascript wont read .post php submit input (in php)

Tags: php, javascript, html

Javascript part...
It stops at the $("#deletar").click...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#deletar").click(function() { // it fails here !!
        var sendu = $("#ids").val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "deletar.php",
            data : "ids=" + sendu,
            success : function(msg, string, jqXHR) {
                $("#result").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the php file... is a echo to other ajax post, and retrieves a list of a mysql db

```
.$row2['amigos']."
</td>
<td><inp ``ut type='submit' name='deletar' id='deletar' value='deletar'
        OnClick='return confirm(\"Tem certeza que quer deletar esta linha?\");'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ids' id='ids' value='".$row2['id']."'>

</td>
</tr>
";
enter code here
```

Comment: Is the `#deletar` a submit button by any chance?

Comment: what happens if click on `deletar` submit buttons ? any error ?

Comment: Yes, deletar is a value of input type submit  !!

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax is being called from a submit button `click`. You haven't done anything to prevent the default behaviour of the submit button, therefore after your ajax call, the browser will submit the form using a traditional request.

In your `click` event, you can `return false` to prevent the form submitting:

```
$("#deletar").click(function(){ //it fails here !!
    var sendu = $("#ids").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"deletar.php",
        data: "ids="+sendu,
        success: function(msg,string,jqXHR){
                $("#result").html(msg);
            }
        }); 

    return false; // <--- stop the form submitting
});
```

You can also use [`e.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stop the form submitting after the submit button has been clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#deletar").click(function (event) {//it fails here !!
        event.preventDefault(); // one of these
        event.stopPropagation(); // lines should do the trick
        var sendu = $("#ids").val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "deletar.php",
            data : "ids=" + sendu,
            success : function (msg, string, jqXHR) {
                $("#result").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```